# Does repetitively calling a static method that enqueues a Retrofit network call maintain the value of the passed arguments correspondingly?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

```
 public static void sendFeedback(final Feedback feedback, final Context context) {
    Call<MyServerResponse> sendFeedbackCall = service.sendFeedback(feedback);

    sendFeedbackCall.enqueue(new Callback<MyServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MyServerResponse> call, @NonNull Response<MyServerResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                feedback.setSent(true); // *do more actions on **that feedback object** based on the response body.*
            } else {
             feedback.setSent(false); // *do more actions on **that feedback object** based on the response body.*
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<MyServerResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
          feedback.setSent(false); // do more actions on **that feedback object** based on the response object.
          Toast.makeText(context,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // use the passed argument **context**
    });
}
```

I am sending multiple objects of type Feedback to the server sequentially using Retrofit by calling the above static method from a for loop.

When trying to access the passed argument which is feedback from inside the callback function, the IDE forced me to make the passed arguments as final.

**Assumption:**

Now **assume** every Network call will take lets say 1 second till I receive the response. But, since I use a for loop to call the sendFeedback static method, it will be called like 10 times before the first response is received back by the Retrofit callback methods.

**Question**: Since the method will end either ways too soon before the thread initialized inside it by Retrofit async call returns a response. Does that mean that the work done inside the callback methods will be on the last passed argument of type Feedback from the for loop, or on a null since the method would have ended by that time anyways?

But, I am sure that at least one passed argument survives since the toast that uses context is shown! Please provide me with an explanation.

And why the IDE is forcing me to make the arguments as final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java requires that if you are going to use a local variable within an anonymous class, it must be final. Basically, any time you have code that looks like

```
void myMethod(A a, B b) {
    C c = new C();
    doSomething(new MyClass() {
        void methodInAnonymmousClass() {
             a.doSomething();
             c.doSomething();
        }
    });
}
```

Any local variables you use inside the anonymous class (a and c in this case) must be final.  It's just a requirement of the language. It's not going to change anything about how your code works. It will still behave the way you expect it to.

Comment: And it seems that the corresponding passed variables are copied in memory for later usage by the anonymous class, as the method would have ended by that time, as it works on another thread as in my case, the values are always correct. But are these variables copied by reference too? Still figuring this out.

Comment: Yes. Variables and objects are separate things in Java. Variables contain _references_ to objects, so when you make a copy of a variable, for example by copying a method parameter into an anonymous class, the copied variable continues to reference the same object, even after the method ends and the original variable ceases to exist.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** In order to access any variable from inside an anonymous class that is created inside the method, that variable must be final. It is no longer necessary to explicitly write the final keyword since Java 8, but the variable must not be changed inside the method. So, after all final is applied implicitly for you.

**Second:** That variable is copied into the anonymous class every time the method is called in order to be used by the created anonymous classes. That's why if you start a thread it will still have the variables to work with, even though that the method scope would have ended by that time and method parameters no longer exist. See the below code:

```
for(int i =0; i<10,i++){
    show(i);
 }
```

---

```
void show(final int param) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                try {
                    wait(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            System.out.print(param);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The above code would print: 12345678910

Same concept applies to the question, where the anonymous class is a Retrofit Callback.